# O que acontece detalhadamente na destruição de uma variável?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber o que realmente acontece por trás do comando `unset` em uma variável no **PHP**.

Acredito que isso aconteça na memória, mas gostaria de aprofundar meu conhecimento em relação a isto e obter a certeza do que acontece através da experiência de alguém.

Comment: A variável é enviada para a anti-matéria do espaço, causando o que conhecemos como "buracos negros".

Comment: Não lembro de todos os detalhes mas basicamente a variável é apenas considerada inacessível para o programa, nada é liberado na memória. O PHP tem uma implementação dinâmica das variáveis, não me lembro bem mas se não me engano todas as variáveis são simplesmente elementos de uma estrutura *hash*. Sei que algumas formas de variáveis são assim mas não lembro se todas são.

Comment: Rogers, depende do contexto da variável, se ela faz parte de um array, apenas é removida a referência do índice, se for uma variável normal e ela estiver no escopo de outra função, ela continua existindo, vai depender de onde veio, que tipo é, e pra onde vai ou foi.
Mas geralmente é liberado da memória ao fim da execução do script, esta liberação da memória nada mais é do que perder a referência de acesso aos bits correspondentes, que serão utilizados novamente para gravar outra informação com outra referência, quando se diz que algo está na memória, quer dizer que tem referência armazenada.

Comment: Vê que coisa complicada, você me diz que sim é eliminada da memorio, enquanto o @bigown diz que talvez não. Acho que vou ficar com essa dúvida. legal seria ver o que está por trás desta função.

Comment: @RogersCorrêa muita calma nessa hora :) a pergunta é nova ainda, grandes chances de vir algo mais definido com o tempo, e em formato de resposta.

Comment: Está mais associado com hardware do que software, é como um HD, mesmo formatando, os dados permanecem lá até que grave por cima novamente, e criando uma nova referência de acesso aos dados...

Comment: @RogersCorrêa Foram ditas coisas diferentes. Ao fim da execução do script eu tenho certeza que é liberada da memória. O script encerra e tudo é liberado. Mas a pergunta é sobre o `unset`, quando ele ocorre a memória não é liberada. De qualquer forma, para você ter algo preciso e confiável vai ter que esperar que alguém mais experiente responda. Pode não ocorrer, pode demorar. Uma outra forma de descobrir é pegar os fontes do PHP e ver o que acontece. Não é fácil mas é uma solução se a resposta for importante.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O php é uma linguagem produzida em C e C++ atualmente [seu código fonte está disponível no github](https://github.com/php/php-src) [informações sobre o uso do unset pode sem encontradas na página oficial do php](http://php.net/). O primeiro conceito que devemos entender é o que realmente é uma variável a confusão principal começa quando não assimila muito bem esse conceito. Uma variável é uma referencia que aponta para um endereço de memória. Como assim?!? Imagine uma memória com capacidade total de armazenamento de de 16 bits, você pode armazenar no máximo 2 bytes (2x8 = 16), você tem o endereço 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 como a menor unidade de medida que nós temos é o bit se fossemos dividir a memória poderíamos dividir em no máximo 16 pedaços. Joãozinho, Maria, Sileno e Manuel querem armazenar coisas la dentro. Joãozinho quer armazenar 8 bits. E pede ao sistema operacional para disponibilizar esse espaço para ele. O sistema operacional vê que é possível armazenar e reserva 8 bits para o Joãozinho e fala para o Joaozinho:
_ Joãozinho, já reservei o seu espaço ele começa na posição 1. 
Eis então que o Joãozinho, malandramente, para não esquecer onde ele pode armazenar da um apelido para esse endereço, para ficar mais fácil de memorizar a a partir de onde ele pode armazenar os dados e da o apelido de var1. Surge então o conceito de variável. Ela serve para armazenar um endereço de memória que para os humanos é um nome mais fácil de assimilar e para as maquinas a localização de uma área de memória.
Trocando em miúdos (em C):

```
void *var1 = malloc(8); // malloc pede ao so que reserve um espaço de 8 bits
// var1 recebe o endereço inicial da posição de memória que o so reservou.
```

Dentro de var1 então Joãozinho pode armazenar qualquer valor, até 8 bits. 
Maria também quer armazenar 8 bits e pede ao SO que reserve esse espaço ele informa a maria que a posição inicial do endereço dela é 9 ela faz o mesmo que o Joãozinho cria um apelido para esse endereço var2. 
Nesse momento todo o espaço da memória está alocado. O sistema operacional não tem como alocar mais nada para ninguém.
Eis então que o Joaozinho da um libera a memoria e devolve para o sistema operacional os 8 bits e a maria também devolve os 8 bits e o sistema operacional passa a ter novamente 16 bits livre.
Trocando em miúdos (em C):

```
free(var1); // libera a memória que começa no endereço 1
free(var2); // libera a memória que começa no endereço 9
```

Sileno então pede 16 bits para o SO o SO reserva esses dados e informa que a posição inicial do endereço dele é 1 ele faz o mesmo que Joãozinho e cria um apelido para esse endereço var3.

Manoel tenta alocar 1 bit, o SO informa que não pode alocar e devolve para Manoel a posição 0 (NULL).

Contudo, gerenciar a memória desse jeito é possível (C é assim), mas demanda muita atenção e pode criar várias problemas se esquecer de liberar a memória.A alocação de pequenos blocos poderia inclusive fazer com que mesmo tendo espaço não fosse possível alocar a memória. Por exemplo:

Joãozinho precisa de 8 bits e o SO tem 9 bits disponível, mas alocou
da seguinte forma do var1 = endereço (1,2,3); var2 = (9,10,11); var3 =
(14); No total foram alocados 7 bits, mas para alocar os 9 bits o so
tem que pegar um espaço sequencial e como esta fragmentada ele apesar
de ter o espaço não tem como alocar os dados e o Joãozinho não tem seu
espaço alocado recebendo um NULL como resposta para o endereço
inicial.

Novos conceitos então foram criados para que a falha humana em relação ao gerenciamento de memória fosse minimizado.

O Garbage Collector permite que ao reservar um espaço da memória para seu programa, você não precisa explicitar a liberação dele quando não utilizá-lo mais, isso porque ele verifica os elementos que não são usados por ninguém e remove.

O Heap e Stack são outros conceitos referente a gerenciamento de memória que são muito interessantes.

[O Heap é a a memória reservada para a alocação dinâmica](http://pt.scribd.com/doc/232127732/gerenciamento-de-memoria-pdf). hum?!?, pois é, nesse a aplicação já aloca um bloco de memória inicial e ao invés de pegar memoria direto do SO, você pega dessa reserva da aplicação.

[Stack (segundo Wiki da Nokia): São regiões da memória onde os dados são inseridos e removidos seguindo a estrutura de dados 'último que entrou primeiro que sai'. Objetos e variáveis declaradas dentro do escopo de funções e métodos estão nessa região da memória.](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Ger%C3%AAncia_de_mem%C3%B3ria)

Ok, mas a pergunta foi sobre o unset, enrolou, falou sobre C/C++ e um monte de baboseira e não respondeu a pergunta...

Pois bem, [o php tem um heap, o Zend MM](https://wiki.php.net/internals/zend_mm) que é responsável pelo gerenciamento de memória, o PHP também implementada o [Garbage Collector](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.gc.php) e o unset? (o código é muito grande, deu preguiça de procurar). Não achou ?! Encontrei funções de unset, para session, [array](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.ze1.zendapi.php), [property](https://wiki.php.net/internals/engine/objects#unset_property) e o unset? (bem não estou enrolando somente encontrei na ultima pesquisa inconformando por não ter conseguido encontrar a reposta) eu encontrei com a ajuda do Google (novidade o unset e todo o resto...) o [unset](https://code.google.com/p/phc/source/browse/trunk/runtime/unset.c?r=3265) que chama o [zend_hash_del](http://php.undmedlibrary.org/manual/de/zend-api.zend-hash-del.php) depois disso ficou claro como o unset funcionava pois achei outro documento a peça final do quebra cabeça. E venho compartilhar com todos vocês o funcionamento do gerenciamento da memória do php e o maldito unset (não fui eu que escrevi e está em inglês). [este documento](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780672327049/samplechapter/067232704X_CH03.pdf), [esse é outro link para o mesmo documento](http://pt.scribd.com/doc/232132550/067232704X-CH03-pdf), pena que só achei no final quando estava terminando de escrever o tópico.

> (Não é citação, só vou fugir do assunto aqui, estou marcando para destacar, retomo depois dessa parte) 
>  Quanto se tem uma memória de 8GB você pode dividir
>   usa memória em muitos espaços de 1 bit. Contudo, Nós entramos em um
>   problema chamado arquitetura, pois é, aquela questão dos 32bits e 64
>   bits. O nosso SO tem que "saber contar" em 32 bits ele só sabe contar
>   até 2^32 ou seja 4294967296 esse é o número máximo que o SO vai poder
>   contar pois ele está limitado a formar um número de até 32 bits. Mas
>   se você dividir sua memória de 8GB vai ter mais do que 4294967296
>   pedaços. O que acontece então ?! O SO só vai usar 4294967296 pedaços e
>   o restante da memória vai ficar ocioso e sedentário. E como resolver
>   isso? a arquitetura de 64 bits 2^64 permite formar
>   18446744073709551616 números. Ai você pode usar seus 8GB e até mais.
>   (Dei uma fugida do assunto aqui, mas vou deixar a questão da
>   arquitetura)

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, bem explicativa.

Comment: A resposta é bem interessante, só estou aguardando ela responder o que foi perguntado.

Comment: Muito boa mesmo, entendi, então é isso que acontece!

Answer (score 9):

### TL;DR

Ao usar [unset()](http://www.php.net/unset) o PHP decrementa um contador interno de sua estrutura básica para armazenamento de tipos compostos chamada `zval`. Quando esse contador atinge zero, a memória utilizada é liberada automaticamente.

---

Para responder a esse tipo de pergunta da forma mais apropriada primeiro é preciso saber como o PHP gerencia suas variáveis, o mais essencial dos recursos da linguagem.

### O que exatamente são variáveis no PHP?

Variáveis no PHP são representadas internamente por um container chamado `zval`, uma estrutura do C definida no arquivo **zend.h** do código-fonte do PHP:

```
struct _zval_struct {
    /* Variable information */
    zvalue_value value; /* value */
    zend_uint refcount__gc;
    zend_uchar type; /* active type */
    zend_uchar is_ref__gc;
};
```

O campo `value`representa o valor efetivo (inteiro, string, objeto…). Em seguida temos dois campos relacionados ao gerenciamento de memória: `is_ref` e `refcount`.

**refcount** é um inteiro indicando quantos símbolos apontam para aquele **zval**. Um símbolo é tipicamente uma variável PHP (como **$a**) mas pode também ser uma variável interna ao/do C, uma vez que outros **zval** também são usados pela *engine*.

**is_ref** é um inteiro representando um valor booleano. Por padrão é definido como zero o que significa que aquele **zval** ainda não foi afetado por uma referência (na sintaxe do PHP `&$a`). quando setado para 1 (um) significa que aquele **zval** é uma referência o que veremos a seguir caracteriza uma **grande** mudança de compartamento quando o PHP opera aquele **zval**.

### Tipos Compostos

Em PHP temos muitas coisas que são **zval**. Por exemplo, quantos **zval** você pode contar nesse pequeno fragmento abaixo:

```
$a = ‘foo’;
```

Obviamente que a resposta mais simples é a correta: Um.

Se fôssemos representar em uma imagem, teríamos algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quanto a este pequeno código?

```
$a = array('foo'=>'bar', 42);
```

Aqui temos três `zval`: A string **bar**, o inteiro **42** e o array que os encapsula. Ilustrando, temos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe as chaves no array. **foo** e **1** não são `zval`, apenas seus valores o são. Vejamos agora como funcionam com objetos:

```
class Foo {
        public $a = 42;
        protected $bar = 'default';
}

$obj = new Foo;
```

Aqui também foram criados três `zval`: Um para o objeto no símbolo **$obj** e um para cada um dos atributos, **$a** e **bar**.

Você irá perceber que, deste ponto de vista, objetos se comportam como arrays pois, assim como eles, são tipos compostos, então eles têm `zval` para eles próprios slém de um para cada tipo que eles contêm. Bem simples!

### Como o PHP gerencia as variáveis?

Agora vamos ver como o PHP gerencia todos esses `zval` quando você, programador, os usa diariamente.

Vamos ignorar por um momento as referências e focar no quão esperto o PHP em não duplicar memória do `zval` quando você copia o conteúdo de uma variável para outra:

```
$a = 'foo';
$b = $a;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima o container `zval` está representado em amarelo. Ele é o que consome memória e é o que você (ou o PHP) deveria se prevenir contra duplicidades e liberá-los o quanto antes.

Em cinza estão representados os símbolos, a svariáveis PHP. os símbolos também consomem memória, mas em quantidades tão pequenas que na maioria das vezes você não precisa se preocupar.

Com isso podemos seguramente dizer que ambos os scripts abaixo consomem a mesma quantidade de memória:

```
// Script 1
$a = 'foo';
$b = $a;

// Script 2
$a = 'foo';
```

Como você deve ter percebido o campo `refcount` foi incrementado quando **$b** foi apontado para outro `zval`. `refcount` é o “truque” por trás do gereciamento de memória nas variáveis do PHP. Através dele sabemos quantos símbolos apontam para um mesmo container `zval`.

### *Copy on Write*

*Copy On Write* (abreviado por *COW*) é outro truque concebido para poupar memória mais genericamente usado em engenharia de software. Significa que o PHP vai copiar a memória ou melhor dizendo alocar uma nova região da/na memória quando você escrever um símbolo **se** este já estiver apontando para outro `zval`. Ex:
:
    $a = "foo";
    $b = $a;
    $a = 17;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro exemplo, importante ao escopo do tópico:

```
$a = "foo";
$b = $a;
$c = $b;
$b = "bar";
unset($a);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe como o PHP manipula o campo `refcount`. Este é incrementado e decrementado a medida que símbolos apontam ou deixam de apontar para um determinado `zval`. Apenas a memória necessária é alocada.

Veja também que o unset() não necessariamente libera memória. unset() vai apenas decrementar o valor `refcount`em um.

Se, e somente se, o valor de `refcount`chegar a zero é que o PHp sabe que nenhum outro símbolo está apontando para aquele `zval` e, então, irá liberá-lo automática e imediatamente.

Reforçando que todo esse comportamento assume que referências não estejam sendo utilizados, daí `refcount` ter se mantido sempre em zero ao longo do detalghamento do processo que é simples e de fácil compreensão.

**Crédito Extra!** Se você quiser se aprofundar no assunto, a [xDebug](http://www.xdebug.org) oferece a função [xdebug_debug_zval()](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_debug_zval) através da qual é possível extrair ambos os valores `refcount` e `is_ref`.

Vejamos agora um exemplo com arrays:

```
$a = array("foo"=>"bar", 1 => 42);
$b = $a["foo"];
$c = $b;
$b = 18;
unset($a['foo']);
$a[1] = $b;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como se pode ver o memso comportamento é aplicado e a mesma importante mantida: Somente quando `refcount` atinge zero o `zval`respectivo é liberado. Nunca antes.

E, novamente, atendendo ao escopo principal do tópico, veja o que acontece com unset(). O `zval`referente ao índice associativo **foo** do array foi eliminado, mas como havia um outro símbolo anteriormente criado (**$c**) o `zval associado à string **bar** foi mantido, tendo apenas seu`refcount`decrescido.

### Funções / Métodos

Sim, funções e métodos são a mesma coisa. Dito isso, vamos ver como eles se comportam com relação a símbolos e `zval`

O que se deve ter em mente é que quando uma função é criada o escopo da mesma criado junto. E com exceção das variáveis globais, aquelas criadas dentro de uma função não podem ser acessadas de fora dela.

Por fim, os argumentos de função bem como seu valor de retornam têm seus respectivos `refcount`incrementados ao invés de ter outros `zval` criados. Vamos a um exemplo:

```
<?php
function foo($var)
{
    $var = "bar";
    return $var;
}

$a = "foobaz";
$b = foo($a);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pilha inicia com a definição do símbolo **$a** e seu respectivo `zval` para uma string a ser usada como argumento da função a ser invocada.

Em seguida temos a invocação da função recebendo **$a** como argumento. Notem que o `refcount` conta para 3 (três): um para o `zval`da string **foobaz** e outros dois para o argumento da função (**$var**) e seus escopo local.

Uma vez com o fluxo dentro da função temos o `refcount` do símbolo **$var** (e consequentemente de **$a**) decrementado pois **$var**, agora, foi realocado para outra string. E agora temos dois `zval` diferentes.
Então temos o retorno da função. O símbolo **$b** é criado e ao invés de um terceiro `zval` ser criado apenas o `refcount`de **$var** é incrementado ao apontar para **$b**.

Por fim, quando a função é finalizada os dois `refcount` dos dois `zval` são decrementados pois tanto o escopo quanto a pilha de consumo em si são destruídos da mesma forma que o [unset()](http://www.php.net/unset).

E tudo isso automaticamente, sem a necessidade de se alocar e liberar memória manualmente.

### Referências

Tudo que foi dito até agora limita-se ao uso “clássico” do PHP, vamos tornar as coisas um pouco mais interessantes com as **referências**.

> Lembrete: referências são definidas em PHP quando você usa o símbolo **&** (*ampersand*)

Exemplo rápido:

```
$a = 'string';
$b = &$a;
$b = 1;
```

Todo mundo com conhecimento da linguagem já deve saber só de olhar o resultado desse *snippet*: **$a** e **$b** têm o memso valor: **o inteiro 1**

Internamente, quando usadas, as referências amarram os símbolos (**$a** e **$b**) ao mesmo `zval`. Você poderia até dizer que é o mesmo que ocorre quando fazendo `$b = $a`.

De fato, é exatamente o que acontece. `$a = $b` ou `$a = &$b` resulta, internamente, na mesma coisa. A diferença é como as referências alteram profundamente o comportamento do PHP quando o *Copy On Write* ocorre, isto é, na linha `$b = 1`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao definirmos os símbolo **$a** criamos um `zval`para a string *string*. Quando definimos o símbolo **$b** e utilizamos o *ampersand* (&) o campo `is_ref` é incrementado e o comportamento de `refcount` continua o mesmo, ou seja, continua sendo incrementado para representar a quantidade de símbolos apontando para àquele `zval`.

Porém a *flag* `is_ref` vai mudar o comportamento do *Copy On Write* do PHP quando você mudar o alterar o símbolo por não mais separar o valor de cada símbolo em dois `zval`distintos, mas ao invés disso alterá-lo diretamente, dando a impressão de que ambos **$a** e **$b** estão ligados.

Simples e eficiente mas que requer atenção dobrada em alguns casos.
Vejamos outro exemplo que demonstra a mudança de comportamento de todo esse “duplicar ou não duplicar memória”:

```
$a = "string";
$b = &$a;
$c = $b;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preste bastante atenção na terceira linha `$c = $b;`

**$b** é uma referência de **$a** e ambos apontam para o mesmo `zval`. Ao criarmos o símbolo **$c** pode-se imaginar que por este apontar para **$b** ele também estaria apontando para **$a** e o `refcount`seria apenas incrementado para **3**.

Mas **não é** isso o que acontece. Por causa da precedência o PHP é forçado a criar um novo `zval`e duplicar a string *string*

Tanto é verdade que se o valor de **$c** for alterado depois de ter sido associado a **$b**, o valor de **$b** (e consequentemente de **$a**) não seriam afetados:

```
$a = "string";
$b = &$a;
//$b = 'foo';
$c = $b;

var_dump( $a, $b, $c ); // string(6) "string" string(6) "string" string(5) "Bruno"
```

Para evidenciar ainda mais, se descomentássemos a linha que altera o valor de **$b** temos:

```
string(3) "foo" string(3) "foo" string(5) "Bruno"
```

Em resumo: **$c** não é uma referência de **$b** apesar deste ter sido definido anteriormente como referência de outro símbolo (**$a**).

E este é o primeiro cuidado que se deve ter ao utilizar referências pois o PHP copia memória em lugares onde você normalmente não esperaria que fosse.

Mais um exemplo, agora com funções:

```
<?php
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var = "bar";
    return $var;
}

$a = "foobaz";
$b = foo($a);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja como o PHP duplicou a string *bar* por causa da referência.  A duplicação de memória ocorreu não quando a atribuição `$var = 'bar';`foi feita, afinal, **$var** é uma referência, mas sim quando do retorno da função, que é o valor e não a referência ora definida.

Nessa hora o `zval`é duplicado pois quando você altera aquilo que a função vai retornar você não está alterando aquilo que afunção recebeu, mesmo que seja uma referência.

Com isso em mente é preciso lembrar que referências não necessariamente poupam memória. Com elas a duplicação de memória é apenas atrasada se comparada com uma atribuição normal, por valor.

Porém, cedo ou tarde, um novo `zval`deverá ser criado, a não ser que você seja muito cuidadoso e use fielmente a referência do início ao fim, sem jamais quebrá-la, explícita ou implicitamente.

Por fim o último dos cuidados a se ter com referências;

```
function foo(&$var)
{
    if (strlen($var) > 3) {
        return $var;
    } else {
        $var .= '_uppercased';
        return strtoupper($var);
    }
}

$value = 'barbaz';
echo foo($value);
```

Sim, esse é um código bem estúpido mas útil para se comentar a respeito. Você seria capaz de adivinhar quando exatamente o PHP precisaria criar um novo `zval`e duplicar o conteúdo?

Você percebeu que **$var** foi passado por referência à função *foo()*. **$var** tem um `is_ref`igual a 1. Mas o que acontece quando você invoca ambos, [strlen()](http://www.php.net/strlen) e [strtoupper()](http://www.php.net/strtoupper)?

Se você checar o manual verá que esse argumentos são passados **por valor** e o argumento de nossa função é passado por referência. Já viu aonde isso vai dar? O PHP vai duplicar a memória a cada invocação de cada uma dessas funções.

Sim, o PHP não tem como saber se [strlen()](http://www.php.net/strlen) vai tentar modificar o argumento.

O que aconteceria se ele tivesse como saber? **$var** seria alterada uma vez que [strlen()](http://www.php.net/strlen) não aceita referências como argumentos.

E como não é isso que queremos, o PHP é forçado a duplicar o `zval` para trabalhar com o valor da variável passada. No entanto, nesse caso ao menos, o `is_ref` seria setado como zero, antes e depois de invocar as ditas funções, e só então a memória usada pelo `zval`seria liberada.

Isso é um desperdício e você foi enganado pelas referências de novo. Vai lá admita! O tradutor aqui admite e nesse momento está deitado no chão gelado chorando. :p

Se **$var** não tivesse sido passada por referência nenhuma duplicação iria acontecer (claro, se você tivesse feito o seu trabalho como programador e tivesse lidado decentemente com aquela concatenação ali).

Mas não há motivo para pânico. Duplicar aquele **barbaz** causaria um impacto de nanossegundos hoje em dia. Mas não é isso o que acontece com arrays grandes e complexos, verdadeiros glutões em termos de performance.

Nesses casos os valores não seriam copiados, apenas teriam seus `refcount` incrementados. Entretanto o array **inteiro** seria copiado.

Pra se ter uma idéia, um array com um milhão de entradas levaria algo em torno de 0.3 segundos no PHP 5.5.

Parece pouco, mas tenha em mente que a grande maioria dos usos do PHP roda a no mínimo a 100 milisegundos mais rápido **E** esses 0.3 segundos leva em conta UMA requisição o que é MUITO diferente de uma Aplicação real com milhares de pessoas acessando o recurso em questão. E pior! Ao mesmo tempo ☠

### Vazamento de Memória e *Garbage Collection*

primeiro vamos ver de forma rápida o que seria *Garbage Collection*. *Garbage Collection*, numa definição livre, é um mecanismo que acompanha o uso dos objetos e libera seus suportes de memória uma vez que eles não possam mais ser alcançados no escopo corrente ou que que não estejam mais sendo usados (pelo programador).

Trazendo essa definição para o PHP e tudo o que já foi dito temos o `refcount` aplicado aos `zval` que, de fato, liberar a memória quando este atinge zero.

Desde o começo o PHP fornece um mecanismo de *garbage collection* para sua variáveis, porém, temos o **Zend Garbage Collector** (ou Zend GC) introduzido no PHP 5.3 que, diferentemente do que se pensa não libera a memória usada (quem faz isso é o próprio PHP) e sim cuida das refrências circulares por você.

O [Manual do PHP](http://www.php.net/gc) tem uma seção bem detalhada, inclusive com imagens, sobre como é o processo de *garbaging collection*.

**Referências Circulares** aparecem em tipos compostos como arrays e objetos. Quando dois tipos compostos se referênciam uns aos outros ou quando um tipo composto se refere a ele mesmo, temos uma referência circular. Isso é ruim porque é difícil de computar quando exatamente eles começam ou devem ser liberados.

Até antes do PHP 5.3 não haviam meios de acompanhar referências circulares e quando você liberava suas variáveis, com [unset()](http://www.php.net/unset), por exemplo, forçando zerar seus `refcount`, o PHP deixava alguns "rastros" das entidades como se elas ainda existissem. Ex:

```
// Criamos duas entidades (objetos)

$a = new ObjA;
$b = new ObjB;

// Criamos a referência circular

$a->b = $b;
$b->a = $a;

// Decrementamos os refcount
unset($a, $b);

/**
 * Deste ponto em diante o não se é mais possível
 * obter os dois zval acima, mas eles ainda existem
 * na memória e o PHP, até antes da versão 5.3
 * nunca iria liberá-los.
 */
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os símbolos são criados e quando as propriedades são setadas temos novos `zval` sendo criados, um para cada propriedade de cada símbolo e os `refcount` incrementados.

unset() destruiu os símbolos e decrementou os `refcount` como esperado. No entanto àqueles criados ao setar as propriedades ficaram lá, esquecidos.

Com o PHP 5.3 um complexo sistema foi introduzido especificamente para acompanhar esses casos que são cada vez mais frequentes a medida que mais e mais programadores gerenciam mais e mais objetos em seus códigos. É fácil de se ter dois objetos em referência circular e você obviamente nem percebe.

Agora o PHP acompanha automaticamente referências circulares e libera a memória por elas usadas de tempo em tempo. Se, porventura, você notar uma referência circular e quiser forçar sua liberação o PHP fornece a função [gc_collect_cycles()](http://www.php.net/gc_collect_cycles) criada especificamente para isso.

Vamos ver como em mais um exemplo:

```
// Criamos duas entidades (objetos)

$a = new ObjA;
$b = new ObjB;

// Criamos a referência circular

$a->b = $b;
$b->a = $a;

// Decrementamos os refcount
unset($a, $b);

/**
 * Forçamos o PHP a limpara a referência circular
 * e exibimos quantos zval foram liberados
 * pelo garbage collector
 */
$cleaned = gc_collect_cycles();

echo $cleaned; /* 2 */
```

Referências circulares consomem memória, mas isso não chega a ser tão preocupante num ambiente Web uma vez que de qualquer maneira o PHP limpa todos os recursos, incluindo as referências circulares, ao fim da Requisição.

O problema se torna bem mais aparente em aplicaçoes CLI de longo ciclo, como por exemplo testes com PHPUnit. Graças ao Zend GC sua curva de memória deve permanecer relativamente simples.

Artigo Original: [Web and PHP](http://webandphp.com/how-php-manages-variables)

Tradução, adaptação e complemento: Bruno Augusto

Comment: Finalmente a tradução ficou pronta u.u'

Comment: Não consigo visualizar as imagens do imgur através do firewall da empresa. =\

Comment: Logo mais eu edito (ou alguém mais, quem sabe) para substituir as imagens externas por uploads aqui no SOPT mesmo. É como eu levei alguns dias para traduzir aos poucos e colher informações complementares eu redigi o artigo / resposta no StackEdit.io

Comment: Muito bom esse post, bem claro e explicado, parabéns!

Comment: *Oh stop it you!* :p

Comment: Fiz o upload das imagens aqui para o SOPT mas adiantou muito pois o site também envia para uma conta do IMGUr própria dele.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, fiz alguns testes e olha o que aconteceu...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código:

```
<?php

var_dump($xacrinha);

print "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>";

$xacrinha = 12;

var_dump($xacrinha);

print "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>";

unset($xacrinha) ;

var_dump($xacrinha);
```

?>

Olhando para isto o que eu entendi? Entendi junto as dicas do pessoal do comentário  que a `unset` não remove da memoria a variável, mas provavelmente ela declara a variável como nula...interessante que pelo que percebi quando coloco o cifrão na frente ele já aloca a memoria para a minha variável. Ou seja no PHP, `unset` apenas declara minha variável como `null`. Sei talvez haja mais para explicar e vou aguardar uma resposta mais consistente...agradeço o pessoal pelos comentários.

Fiz outro teste e a dúvida continua:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olha o código, declarar uma variável como `null` é diferente de unset, estou chegando a conclusão de que realmente é sim, eliminado da memoria.

```
<?php

var_dump($xacrinha);

print "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>";

$xacrinha = null;

var_dump($xacrinha);

print "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>";

unset($xacrinha) ;

var_dump($xacrinha);

?>
```

Comment: Não li o código fonte do PHP para saber como funciona o exatamete o unset e posso estar dando uma explicação equivocada. Criar uma variável é reservar alocar um endereço de memória, a variável é uma forma de apontar para esse físico da memória, dentro dessa área você armazena dados. Após utilizado você deveria liberar esse endereço, mas o PHP não trabalha por padrão com a liberação desse endereço de memória de imediato. Acredito que o PHP armazene as variáveis em uso em heap e o unset apenas remova essa variável desse heap. Continua...

Comment: Não sei @SilenoBrito,  me parece muito mais que o PHP substitui o valor d variável alocada pelo valor `null`.

Comment: O php por sua vez aloca uma quantidade de memória inicial para executar o que precisa que pode crescer de acordo com a necessidade da instrução executada e de tempo em tempo deve executar uma especie de garbage collector para se necessário liberar o espaço não utilizado. O unset dessa forma serveria para marcar para o php o que pode ser reutilizado quanto ele tiver a necessidade de utilizar mais recursos de memória. E evita a segui mentação da memória, alocando vários espaços pequenos em diferentes locais da memória.

Comment: Sim, pode ser realmente. Mas isso anularia a questão declarar como null a variável?? Ainda sim fazendo o teste continuo com esse entendimento e talvez ele tenha mesmo este recurso de saber o que pode ser reutilizado. Agora sim vai começar a dar nó no cerebelo.

Comment: Não entendi a questão de declarar a variável como null, uma variável como valor null existe e ocupa espaço (com base em C)

Comment: Sim por isso mesmo. Não é removido, apagado, eliminado da memoria, simplesmente pelo que entendo, a unset no PHP somente diz que a variável xyz = null.

Comment: Não necessariamente, uma variável quando setada como null existe existe, a variável com o unset deixa de existir. Para entender melhor eu aconselho uma leitura sobre o conceito de Garbage Collector (http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coletor_de_lixo_(inform%C3%A1tica) e (http://javafree.uol.com.br/artigo/1386/Introducao-ao-Garbage-Collection.html).

Comment: Muito obrigado @SilenoBrito!

Comment: @RogersCorrêa não sei quanto a memória, mas quando você efetuou var_dump numa variavel inexistente apareceu uma notice: `a variavel está definida`, mas como o PHP faz para aparecer apenas uma *notice* e não um **erro fatal**? Acredito que o compilador ao interpretar, assume temporariamente que o valor de váriaveis inexistentes é *null*, mas ainda sem defini-las, pois assim ele pode continuar executando o código "sem erros". com base nisso acredito que o PHP substitui vars inexistentes por null, por isso em `var_dump($naoExiste)` o valor de $naoExiste é temp. `null`

Comment: Ah, e segundo a documentação do tipo NULL: http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.null.php

Uma variavel é nula quando: **ela foi apagada com unset()**, ela ainda não recebeu nenhum valor ainda, ou foi definida com null.

Comment: Acho que você está confuso entre o que é a variável e que é o valor que ela contém. Quando você usa unset, ou atribui outro valor a uma variável (como `null`), a memória ocupada pelo valor anterior é marcada como "coletável" pelo GC.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu sei a diferença entre a memória heap e a stack. O problema é saber o que o PHP faz e onde ele elimina isto ou simplesmente seta um valor ou não.

Comment: A variável deixa de existir ou ela recebe o valor `null`??

Comment: Com `unset` ela deixa de existir.

Comment: Mas onde está a prova disto?

Comment: Se eu soubesse, já tinha postado uma resposta :)

Comment: Teria como eu fazer uma comparação entre C e PHP onde a minha variável ocupa espaço??