# Qual é a finalidade do unset como cast no PHP?

Tags: php, cast

A partir do PHP 5, há uma forma de dar uma cast a fim de converter um determinado valor para `NULL`.

Exemplo:

```
$teste = 'teste';

var_dump((unset)$teste); // NULL

$outroTeste = (unset) funcao();

var_dump($outroTeste); // NULL
```

Eu consigo entender que `unset($var)` destrói uma variável, porém a expressão `(unset) $var` converte a variável para `NULL`.

Mas enfim:

- Qual é a finalidade dessa implementação - o `unset` como cast?
- `$var = NULL;` já não seria o suficiente?
- Há algum caso onde seria importante o uso de cast para unset `(unset)`?

Comment: Pelo pouco que entendo e li em diversos blogs de especialistas em PHP, a maioria ou quase todos é unânime no uso do unset para micro otimizações.

Não tenho links agora, mas se quiser saber mais, pesquise por "php micro optimization unset" ou algo do tipo.

Eu costumo utilizar sempre em todos os objetos que não serão mais usados no decorrer do script.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23737/250

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Qual é a finalidade dessa implementação?

Como [explicado pelo Papa Charlie](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43759), ela usa a sintaxe de conversão de tipos para gerar um valor `null`. Na linguagem é possível fazer *casting* para qualquer tipo primitivo da linguagem, como strings e números, incluindo o tipo `null`. É estranho, porém menos estranho que escolher a sintaxe `(unset)` em vez de `(null)`.

> `$var = NULL`; já não seria o suficiente?

Seria, usar um `null` literal é o suficiente na maioria dos casos.

> Há algum caso onde seria importante o uso de `(unset)`?

"Importante" seria um termo forte demais, mas um sujeito no SO em inglês diz usar isso para [desaninhar uma cadeia de condicionais](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23312054/825789), aplicando sobre o retorno de uma função, e como parte de uma expressão condicional.

### PHP 7.2

A partir do PHP 7.2 o cast `(unset)` está em desuso, o que indica que provavelmente será removido em uma versão futura do PHP:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php#migration72.deprecated.unset-cast

Comment: valeu! parece que, no caso da última resposta, realmente se torna uma expressão útil (apesar de eu não querer utilizar assim)

Comment: Boa atualização @GuilhermeNascimento.

Answer (score 4):

> Qual é a finalidade dessa implementação?

Creio que esteja se referindo ao uso `(unset) $var`. Essa forma tem relação com a tipagem da variável, assim como `(int) $var`, ou `(string) $var`... o uso de `(unset) $var` vai mudar o tipo da variável para *null*.

*Casting a variable to null using `(unset) $var` will not remove the variable or unset its value* [(**DOC**)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php#language.types.null.casting)

---

> `$var = NULL` já não seria o suficiente?

Há momentos em que você pode precisar destruir uma variável e não simplesmente tê-la como nula, e ao usar `$var = NULL`, *$var* continuará existindo. Porém, para alteração de *tipo*, sim, `$var = NULL` poderia ser suficiente já que produz o mesmo efeito que `(unset) $var`.

Entretanto, se você mantém um padrão para tipagem, o uso de `(unset) $var` pode ser mais conveniente que `$var = NULL`, pois no segundo caso você está alterando o tipo atribuindo um novo valor, reescrevendo a variável.

Um exemplo:

```
#1
$var = (int)'123'

#2
$var = 123
```

Em ambos os casos minha *$var* é um tipo int. No primeiro eu forcei a tipagem de string para integer e no segundo atribui um valor integer.

---

> Há algum caso onde seria importante o uso de `(unset)`?

Sobre isso há muita explicação na própria [*DOC*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) da função, mas não sei se você se refere à tipagem `(unset) $var` ou à remoção da variável com `unset( $var )`.

---

Não sei se era exatamente isso que você queria saber, não ficou muito claro se era sobra a função ou a tipagem. Se precisar eu tento fazer uma atualização.

Comment: O pessoal passou o negativo com uma ferocidade... Nem a DOC foi perdoada :) Talvez uma outra boa alma possa iluminar minha falha.

Comment: Eu acho que a sua resposta foi bem elaborada sim :). Porém ainda fiquei na dúvida quanto ao PHP ter implementado essa funcionalidade, se é realmente utilizável ou não (porque, por não ter encontrado uma utilidade, parece que é uma funcionalidade inútil)

Comment: Isso pode ser uma questão pessoal. Eu achei interessante mudar a tipagem sem precisar redefinir um valor. Sua dúvida é quando usar?

Comment: Depois de tanto tempo, resolvi dar um tapa nos detalhes da pergunta :). E não fui eu que dei o -1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters e nem eu :) rs