# O que é Clone-on-write (Cow)?

Tags: ponteiro, rust, smart-pointer

Estou estudando Rust e recentemente descobri a existência do [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html), um *smart-pointer* que funciona para fazer *Clone-on-write*.

A descrição da página me pareceu confusa, já que não tenho muito conhecimento sobre o assunto.

- O que é *Clone-on-write*?
- Para que serve o *smart-pointer* `Cow` do Rust?

---

<sup>Devo observar que o termo “Clone” advém das semânticas de *ownership* do Rust. A maioria das outras linguagens que implementam isso provavelmente referem-se a essa estrutura como *Copy on write*.</sup>

Comment: Aqui tem uma explicação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23737. O exemplo é em PHP, mas a lógica do copy-on-write é a mesma em todas as linguagens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O conceito na verdade é bem simples, mas o uso em Rust não é tanto, como quase tudo em Rust.

A técnica de copiar quando houver escrita tem a ver com [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103460/101)), então você tem um objeto que é passado por referência para algum lugar, portanto o objeto não é copiado, apenas tem um ponteiro para o objeto. Em tese essa forma permite que a função mexa no conteúdo desse objeto, porém nesse caso não quer que o objeto seja modificado, ele deve ser imutável, e é aí que entra a técnica. Se uma alteração for pedida (escrita) o objeto será copiado para um novo objeto para proceder a alteração nele deixando imune o objeto original.

Desta forma você tem um custo baixo para o uso normal que provavelmente não escreverá nada, mas também a proteção da imutabilidade se uma alteração for feita no objeto.

O tipo `string` da maioria das linguagens é o melhor exemplo disso. Muita gente não entende porque a alteração no texto não é refletido quando sai de uma função por exemplo. É porque usa a técnica de Copy on Write. A semântica do tipo é de valor então o normal seria copiar o objeto, mas isso custa caro em um objeto potencialmente grande que é uma *string*, ao mesmo tempo que você **pode** querer mexer no texto. Então ele não te cobra até que você precise disso, o tipo sabe que não pode deixar o objeto ser mudado, ele se encarrega de providenciar uma cópia se tentar alterar algo.

A técnica de COW é justamente o que confunde, a pessoa espera que que se o objeto permite uma alteração ela deveria ver a mudança em qualquer lugar onde acesse o objeto, mas ela não percebe que houve uma cópia. Curioso porque se a pessoa pensar em tipo por valor não é difícil entender, esse tipo sempre faz cópia, mesmo que não tenha um *write*. O COW alio as duas coisas.

Tipos originalmente mutáveis nunca usam o COW. lembrando que a preferência de Rust é pelos tipos imutáveis.

## `Cow`

O tipo `Cow` é justamente um ponteiro pronto para lidar com isso onde você sabe que a semântica é essa. Ele é necessário para abstrair se essa referência é de propriedade (*owned*) ou emprestada (*borrowed*), conforme as regras bem conhecidas por quem entende de Rust. Pelo que entendi isso é necessário porque não se sabe ainda se você terá um objeto novo ou não, não sabe se o objeto resultante passa ser seu ou é só o empréstimo feito quando passou.

Eu acho o exemplo da documentação instrutivo:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn abs_all(input: &mut Cow<[i32]>) {
    for i in 0..input.len() {
        let v = input[i];
        if v < 0 {
            // Clones into a vector if not already owned.
            input.to_mut()[i] = -v;
        }
    }
}

// No clone occurs because `input` doesn't need to be mutated.
let slice = [0, 1, 2];
let mut input = Cow::from(&slice[..]);
abs_all(&mut input);

// Clone occurs because `input` needs to be mutated.
let slice = [-1, 0, 1];
let mut input = Cow::from(&slice[..]);
abs_all(&mut input);

// No clone occurs because `input` is already owned.
let mut input = Cow::from(vec![-1, 0, 1]);
abs_all(&mut input);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Rust/Cow.rs).