# Qual é a diferença entre read only e imutável?

Tags: c#, .net, imutabilidade, coleção

Especialmente no contexto do C# e .NET, o que diferencia as coleções *read only* e *immutable*? Por que tem os dois conceitos que parecem a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma coleção *read only*, como o nome diz, só pode ser usada para leitura. Ela não possui mecanismos funcionais que permitam mudar o conteúdo da coleção. Ou não consegue chamar um método ou acessar um campo que permita mudar o dado, ou tem um método/propriedade que lança uma exceção impedindo a alteração. Ela foi criada para impedir a escrita.

Ela pode se basear em uma outra coleção existente que permite escrita. Ou seja, é possível ter um objeto dessa coleção somente leitura que referencia outra coleção e, portanto, é possível sim alterar os dados da coleção, só não dá para fazer isso através desse objeto *read only*.

Essas duas são as características marcantes deste tipo de coleção.

Se assemelha ao que acontece quando usa um `readonly`, o compilador não deixa mudar o conteúdo, mas se tiver outra referência para o mesmo objeto que permita escrever, o objeto pode ser escrito. Ser *read only* não garante que o objeto nunca será mudado, é uma questão contextual, onde você prometeu que será somente leitura é cumprido, mas não onde não há essa promessa.

Já a coleção *immutable* tem mecanismos para alterar o dado da coleção. Péra aí... se é imutável, não deveria mexer nela!

Mas é isso mesmo, e essa é a mudança mais visível que acaba tendo duas consequências. Além de poder mexer na coleção ela garante a imutabilidade do objeto sempre, ao contrário do caso anterior. Mas como?!?!? Ficou confuso.

Este tipo de coleção usa uma técnica chamada [COW (*copy on write*)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/510544/101). Toda tentativa de mudar o conteúdo produzirá uma cópia do objeto e alteração ocorrerá no novo objeto, entregando a nova versão para quem está manipulando ali, mas preservando o objeto original sem alterações, então em outros lugares que acessam o objeto original não verão mudanças na coleção, o mantendo imutável.

Qual é coleção imutável mais famosa mesmo não tendo um `Immutable` no nome? É a `string`. É exatamente assim que ela funciona. Se você tentar mudar algo nela, não dá erro, mas não altera o objeto original.

Imutabilidade não é o mesmo que constância ou somente leitura. Os conceitos precisam ser bem entendidos, além do C#, embora a história nos mostre que cada tecnologia costuma ter sua própria interpretação de como usa cada um.

Então pense bem qual usar quando há concorrência, e veja se faz o que deseja. E se preocupe com cópias de objetos muito grandes, isso pode matar o desempenho da sua aplicação, mesmo que pareça que não está copiando nada. E pode [ocupar muita memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16050/101) e gerar pressão no GC.

- [Somente leitura](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Imutável](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Concorrente](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

Estas últimas coleções são mais adequadas quando deseja concorrência em alguns cenários, mas pode ter um desempenho pior em alguns casos por causa do travamento que é usado nos seus acessos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).